# how to set up auto mapping in sqlbulkcopy

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In our project we use Linq2SQL, but now we need to have a possibility to quickly insert nearly 15k rows in database table, so i wrote an extension method:

```
public static void BulkInsertBigData(Table<Maintenance> maintenance, IEnumerable<Maintenance> maintenancesToInsert)
    {

            using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(maintenance.Context.Connection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls))
            {
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("FacilityId", "FacilityId");
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("ParentFacilityId", "ParentFacilityId");
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("StartTime", "StartTime");
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("EndTime", "EndTime");
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("ExpirationTime", "ExpirationTime");
                //copy.ColumnMappings.Add("DispatcherUserName", "DispatcherUserName");
                copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Maintenance";
                var data = maintenancesToInsert.ToDataTable();
                copy.WriteToServer(data);
            }

    }
```

Maintanance is auto-generated Linq2SQL class. This code works great when i uncomment ColumnMappings lines, but they doesn't fit, because if somebody will change dbml this code won't work(this code isn't agile :) ).  `ToDataTable()` is a reflection-based method, which converts List of Maintenance to DataTable.

I'll be gratefull for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
public static void BulkInsertBigData<T>(Table<T> definition, IEnumerable<T> rows)
{
    using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(definition.Context.Connection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls))
    {
        var meta = definition.Context.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(T));
        foreach (var col in meta.DataMembers)
        {
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.Member.Name, col.MappedName);
        }
        copy.DestinationTableName = meta.Table.TableName;
        var data = rows.ToDataTable();
        copy.WriteToServer(data);
    }
}
```

or even better: do away with `DataTable` via [FastMember](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember):

```
public static void BulkInsertBigData<T>(Table<T> definition, IEnumerable<T> rows)
{
    using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(definition.Context.Connection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls))
    {
        var meta = definition.Context.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(T));
        var members = new List<string>(meta.DataMembers.Count);
        foreach (var col in meta.DataMembers)
        {
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.Member.Name, col.MappedName);
            members.Add(col.Member.Name);
        }
        copy.DestinationTableName = meta.Table.TableName;
        using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(rows, members.ToArray()))
        {
            copy.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
    }
}
```